# Slick Carousel for WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Trying to get the slick carousel working in wordpress, i have enqueued the files from the cdn and they are being found [ss of slick.js and css files](http://prntscr.com/avx3kn) the structure is in the template file im using, then i have the call before the closing body tag, all the files seem to be found but the slider wont work, is there something im doing wrong or does wordpress interfere with adding normally like this? i do not want to use a plugin as i want to expand on this later.

```
<div class="slider">
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors? WordPress typically uses `jQuery` over `$` to avoid conflicts, and scripts are usually enqueued via `wp_enqueue_script` in a template, functions.php, or plugin. How are you adding your script?

Answer (score 0):

Is your `$( '.slider' ).slick...` function being called before or after the slickjs is loaded from the CDN? You said slick is loading before the closing body tag. If your call is happening before slick is loaded (ie, before slick's `<script...>` tag, it won't work.

You'll need to:

1. Move slickjs to load in the header before you call it, or
2. Move your code to the bottom after slickjs is loaded.

Though you call it in `$( document ).ready...`, this means that all of the DOM elements have been loaded, but it doesn't necessarily means that all of the external scripts have been loaded. File/loading order still matters and this is likely your problem.

Comment: yeah everything is queued right, changed to using owl carousel and it works so might have just been an issue with slick and wordpress.